# Modelling class

Tags: c#, modeling

I try to model class where situation is similar to:

```
public class Car
{
private List<Gratis> _gratises=new List<Gratis>();

public List<Gratis> Gratises
  {
          get { return _gratises; }
          set { _gratises= value; }
       }

public class Gratis
{
public string Name {get;set;}

public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

In one place user manages list of gratises. He can Add, Remove, or Edit gratises.

In second module user can manages cars:

He can add or remove gratis to car.

Is my model ok ?

If is, how implement this?

I have datagridview and:

get list of gratis from database, and next get a list of gratis of car ?

Or maybe add IsChecked field ?

Sql Server 2005. asmx, and WinForms

Comment: is this a web site? A desktop application? Have you tried your design and if so what issues have you encountered, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at M.Fowler refactoring approach [Encapsulate Collection](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/encapsulateCollection.html)

Also note that in get properties return read-only collection:

```
public List<Gratis> Gratises
```

{
  get { return _gratises.AsReadOnly(); }
}

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good, 2 considerations:

1. Why is `_gratises` public? it is
   accessible through `Gratises`, it
   should probably be private
2. Do you mind if someone replaces the
   "gratises" list in its entirety? If
   you do, I would remove the setter
   and add `AddGratis(Gratis)` and
   `RemoveGratis(Gratis)` methods that proxy to
   the underlying List.

Comment: Why is _gratises public? -it was mistake :) Conception with Add and RemoveGratis(gratis) looks fine :)